# Compiling without "-L /usr/local/lib" yields a "cannot connect to socket" error while trying out jaeger opentracing in C++

Tags: c++, jaeger, opentracing

I'm trying out OpenTracing Jaeger and have the following file `test.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <opentracing/tracer.h>
#include <jaegertracing/Tracer.h>
#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>
#include <iostream>

void setUpTracer(const char* configFilePath)
{
    auto configYAML = YAML::LoadFile(configFilePath);
    auto config = jaegertracing::Config::parse(configYAML);
    auto tracer = jaegertracing::Tracer::make(
        "example-service", config, jaegertracing::logging::consoleLogger());
    opentracing::Tracer::InitGlobal(
        std::static_pointer_cast<opentracing::Tracer>(tracer));
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  setUpTracer(argv[1]);
  std::cout<<"Hello\n";
  return 0;
}
```

And consider `config.yml` to be:

```
disabled: false
reporter:
    logSpans: true
sampler:
  type: const
  param: 1
```

Now if I compile `test.cpp` with `g++ test.cpp -lopentracing -ljaegertracing -lyaml-cpp` and run `./a.out config.yml`, I get a

```
ERROR: cannot connect to socket: Cannot connect socket to remote address { scheme="http", host="127.0.0.1", port=5778, path="/sampling", query="" }
```

While if I compile with `g++ test.cpp -L /usr/local/lib -lopentracing -ljaegertracing -lyaml-cpp`, I get a good

```
INFO: Initializing logging reporter
Hello
```

The contents of my `/usr/local/lib` are:

```
cmake                               libopentracing.so.1.6.0    libthriftqt.so
libjaegertracing.a                  libthrift-0.11.0.so        libthrift.so
libjaegertracing.so                 libthrift.a                libthriftz-0.11.0.so
libjaegertracing.so.0               libthrift_c_glib.a         libthriftz.a
libjaegertracing.so.0.6.0           libthrift_c_glib.la        libthriftz.la
libopentracing.a                    libthrift_c_glib.so        libthriftz.so
libopentracing_mocktracer.a         libthrift_c_glib.so.0      libyaml-cpp.a
libopentracing_mocktracer.so        libthrift_c_glib.so.0.0.0  pkgconfig
libopentracing_mocktracer.so.1      libthrift.la               python2.7
libopentracing_mocktracer.so.1.6.0  libthriftqt-0.11.0.so      python3.6
libopentracing.so                   libthriftqt.a
libopentracing.so.1                 libthriftqt.la
```

I'm using Jaeger in conjunction with a larger project involving ROS and get the same error even if I `add_compile_options(-L /usr/local/lib)` for `CMakeLists.txt` of the appropriate package; so, I wanted to better understand what the exact cause of the above error is, so hopefully that helps me to fix the one involved in ROS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the configuration of Jaeger address. Since you did not provided it, it is trying to connect to the default one, which is TCP protocol, `127.0.0.1` and port 5778.
Check for details the configuration section [here](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-client-cpp#updating-sampling-server-url).

Comment: Well, yes, but what is it that causes that error to disappear in the presence of `-L /usr/local/lib` compilation option?

Comment: Also, the config file takes effect only if the "-L /usr/local/lib" compiler option is specified; otherwise, there seems to be no effect.